# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

Tags: java, certificado-digital

Estou tentando autenticar em uma página Web com certificado digital, mas ocorre o erro acima.

Há um "workaround": Importar o certificado no Windows e reexportar. Nesse processo, o arquivo é acrescido de certas informações (normalmente o tamanho passa de 4k para 10k) e a autenticação ocorre sem problemas.

Perguntas: Quais informações faltam no certificado que impedem a autenticação? E como solucionar o problema via java, de modo que o usuário não necessite manipular o certificado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de fazer um diff entre o log da autenticação SSL do certificado original e do alterado, encontrei a solução.

A informação adicionada ao certificado pelo Windows é o *certificate chain*.

Para adicionar ao certificado, precisei fazer o seguinte:

1. Adicionar os certificados da cadeia ao resource do projeto, e criar um método que carrega a cadeia do resource para um array;
2. Criar um KeyStore vazio, e copiar os certificados do KeyStore original para ele usando o método setKeyEntry(). Este método recebe como um dos argumentos a *chain*.

Usando o novo KeyStore gerado, a autenticação funcionou perfeitamente.